# MSI Embedded UI - How do I change the states of features?

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I have a `.msi` installer with Embedded UI on WPF. Everything works!
**Except for one thing..** I can't figure out how to change the request state of the features. When receiving information about a collection of features via Session.Features property - catching the exception *"The handle is invalid"*.

After reading the documentation, I realized that the features are not loaded into memory. And besides, you need to set the installation level via `Session.SetInstallLevel(installLevel)`, i thinked...
But also catching the same exception. After I find out that it is necessary to start the costing process by calling `CostInitialize`, `FileCost` and `CostFinalize` in row. But it is also not possible to call these actions via `Session.DoAction(actionName)`.

I also tried to get a list of features while the installation was running through `IEmbeddedUI.ProcessMessage(...)` - everything was also unsuccessful and the same exception. There is little information about this on the Internet, I can't get any sense before ChatGPT... it remains only to ask for help here :(

**I don't want to use managed bootstrapper app/burn engine for that purposes. please do not offer to use it without solid facts, thanks!**

specs:

- WiX Toolset - v3.14
- WPF - .NET Framework v4.8
- OS: Win11

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd be happy to look at this if you can share a repos with a minimal example.